# Selenium IDE: How to detect the xpath's if div id's , class are randomly generated every time?

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to detect the xpath or css but everytime I run the script, the div id's and class names change which there by fails the script.

```
<div class="yui-dt-bd" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  <table id="yuievtautoid-0" summary="" style="margin-top: 0px;">
   <tr id="yui-rec28" class="yui-dt-rec yui-dt-first yui-dt-even yui-dt-selected" style="">
    <td id="yui-gen52" class="yui-dt23-col-professorId yui-dt-col-professorId yui-dt- sortable yui-dt-first" headers="yui-dt23-th-professorId ">
<div id="yui-gen51" class="yui-dt-liner">1</div>
</td>
<td id="yui-gen44" class="yui-dt23-col-professorName yui-dt-col-professorName yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-last" headers="yui-dt23-th-professorName ">
<div id="yui-gen43" class="yui-dt-liner">John Power</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I had written xpath=//*[@id="yui-gen46"], but id's keep changing. Tried writing table id too. But it does not work.
xpath=id('yuievtautoid-1').

Appreciate some input .

Comment: What node do you want to find?

Comment: Aleh Douhi's answer below will work for you. You are basically looking for the **contains** operator in XPath. My only comment is this seems like your site is not written for testability. How testable a site is, is key for Selenium Tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a part of class or id that is not changed. For example:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'col-professorName')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(@id, 'yuievtautoid')]
```

or CSS versions:

```
css=*[class*="col-professorName"]
css=*[id^="yuievtautoid"]
```

Comment: also, to make the selections more robust, apply additional criteria such as parent, child elements, `position()`, etc.